# What is this symbol that looks like Ø on a schematic?

Tags: schematics, symbol

I'd like to ask about this "empty set" like symbol with a diagonal line through a circle, as shown in the picture below. I have found it in an old electrical schematic. What is it exactly?

[image: Scan of schematic]

Comment: It's a connector.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are terminals. Usually they indicate where external devices are connected to a board or panel and also for inter-connections between boards or panels.

In this case I would expect that devices 17 and 2 are wired to terminals (screw or solder-post) on the main assembly.